# Is Quantifier Elimination possible in this convexity problem?

Tags: convex-geometry, convex-hulls, quantifier-elimination

Given $a$, $b$ and $c$ real numbers, the following statements are equivalent:

1. $$\exists x \in \mathbb{R}; ax^2 + bx + c = 0$$
2. $$b^2-4ac \geq 0$$

Note that the first statement has a quantifier ($\exists$) while the second one is quantifier free. This is an example of quantifier elimination, a process which I have not studied carefully yet though.

Let $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ be elements of $S^2$. Consider the statement:

$$ \exists c_1, c_2, c_3 \in \mathbb{R}; c_1^2+c_2^2+c_3^2 = 1 \text{ and } c_1^2v_1 + c_2^2v_2 + c_3^2v_3 = \mathbf{0}.$$

Can one replace such a statement with some quantifier-free statements? If so, is it easy to figure out what they are explicitly?

Edit 1: note that a necessary and sufficient condition for the statement I am interested in to hold is that the kernel of the $3$-by-$3$ matrix $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ must contain a nonzero vector in the closure of the first octant. Equivalently, a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (the kernel), a closed cone (the closure of the first octant) and $S^2$ must intersect non-trivially. This is essentially a linear program...

Edit 2: for generic $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ on $S^2$, the statement I am interested in is equivalent to $\det(v_1,v_2,v_3) = 0$ and either $w_1 \times w_2$ or $-w_1 \times w_2$ belong to the closure of the first octant, where $w_1$ (resp. $w_2$) is the first (resp. second) row of $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$.

Comment: Why don't you use a CAS to perform QE on a test instance to see what it produces? If you don't want to install QEPCAD, Mathematica does QE.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, you are right. Thank you for mentioning QEPCAD. I will look it up and possibly try to install it.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, it seems also SageMath can handle QE. I have that installed. I will try that. Thank you!

Comment: If I understand correctly, given $3$ points on the $2$-sphere, you want to determine whether their convex hull contains the origin, and write a quantifier-free formula that allows one to decide. Instead of working with convex combinations, one could relax and work with affine combinations, which should boil down to linear algebra, namely, to studying an augmented matrix. If no affine combination touches the origin, then no convex combination does so either.